# Coping actual transform in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to copy an actual transform state of the player, so when my enemy can't see the player, he will walk to the last position he was at.

```
lastVisiblePlayerPosition = nearestPlayer();
```

returns me a reference to an object, but i want to make "copy" of its actual position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a copy of position of some transform or gameObject do this:

```
Vector3 copyOfPosition = someTransform.position;
```

This will create new variable called copyOfPosition that will save the current position of transform whose reference is stored in someTransform.